# Which is better HTTPUNIT or and headless browser

Tags: headless-browser, http-unit

I am trying to compare it for speed, can they handle xpahts, stability, screenshots, popups.

We have a java based framework and we currently use HTTPUnit for our testing which dont have any UI importance. We were doing research and seeing if we could replace HTTPUnit with a headless browser if that is better.

Thanks

Comment: I would be surprised if a headless browser would be faster than HTTPUnit or any 'direct' http testing library.